# Passing GET/POST parameters to shiny app

Tags: java, r, shiny

I want to pass `GET`/`POST` parameters to shiny web app and use that passed values inside R code. The app is hosted on **shiny-server**. Is it feasible? If not then is there any other alternative by which I can pass arguments to shiny app?

Comment: what do you mean by pass arguments? If you mean try to interact programmatically with a Shiny app via an API, AFAIK that isn't possible. Or are you talking about within the app itself?

Comment: I want to interact pro grammatically using java application.

Comment: yeah, i don't think you can, but i'd ask Rstudio folks http://shiny.rstudio.com/help/

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/8ZpNyzPKaTg